# UIScrollView paging from center to left and right

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I made a horizontal UIScrollView, with paging enabled. This allow me to "swipe" a certain view away. The problem I have is that the scrollview is positioned to the left. I can only scroll (read: swipe) my certain view to the left. I also want to let it swipe to the right, so both sides. I think it's a problem with centering the UIScrollView. I tried a lot of things but it all didn't work out.

Here's my code (vertScroll is the horizontal scrollView):

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


     vertScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(3*375, 232);
    vertScroll.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 232);
    vertScroll.pagingEnabled = YES;

    vertScroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
    vertScroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;

    vertScroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake(375, 0);


    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 green:125.0 blue:71.0 alpha:1.0]];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"blabla";

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
     @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],
       NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"StoneSansBold" size:21]}];

    self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
    self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 800);

    UIBlurEffect *blur = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];

    // add effect to an effect view
    self.effectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc]initWithEffect:blur];
    self.effectView.alpha = 0.9;
    self.effectView.frame = CGRectMake(self.coverImage.frame.origin.x, self.coverImage.frame.origin.y+108, self.coverImage.frame.size.width, 34);

    // add the effect view to the image view
[self.coverImage addSubview:self.effectView];

   [self.cellView addSubview:self.seismo];


    self.seismo = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, self.coverImage.frame.size.height/2, 40, 40)];
    self.seismo.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-0.gif"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-1.gif"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-2.gif"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-3.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-4.gif"], nil];
    self.seismo.animationDuration = 1.0f;
    self.seismo.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [self.seismo startAnimating];
    [self.cellView addSubview:self.seismo];
    self.seismo.alpha = 0.0;

    [self.cellView setFrame:CGRectMake(375, 0, 375, 232)];




           // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Explanation with an illustration:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make 3 pages, so the contentSize should be 3 times the size of one page, as far as i can see, that is happening.

Now make sure the user always starts on page 2 (the center page), do this by setting the contentOffset to 1x the width of the scrollView for the x coordinate and 0 for the y coordinate.

After that, the user should be able to scroll left and right.

PS: by looking at your code, it seems like you are assuming everybody uses an iPhone 6 (width of 375pt), you might want to use the calculated width (by using `self.view.frame.size.width` or something relative)

Comment: Did that, but the "certain view" is now located on the left side (so page 1) of the scrollView. How can I center it (or put it on page 2) in the scrollView?

Comment: Just make sure the frame is set correctly, so for page 1 the frame is going to be: `CGRectMake(0,0,width,height)`, for page 2 (center) it's going to be: `CGRectMake(width,0,width,height)` and for page 3 it's going to be `CGRectMake(width * 2,0,width,height)`

Comment: Did that as well, but it still stays left in the scrollView, so on page 1.

Comment: Can you also post the code you use to fill the scrollView?

Comment: "cellView" = "certain view"

Comment: and the scrollview is filled with "cellView"

Comment: Is cellView a regular UIView?

Comment: Yes, it is a regular UIView

Comment: If you log the frame of the cellView, what does it give back? e.g. `NSLog(@"cellView frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cellView.frame))`

Comment: It gives this back: cellView frame: {{375, 0}, {375, 232}}

Comment: Strange.. Have you tried to enable 'Color Blended Layers' in the simulator? It's under the 'Debug' menu. That might shed a little light on the situation

Comment: What does that thing exactly mean? It highlights layers with green and red, what does that mean?

Comment: It just highlights all the blended layers, so you can see how the element is positioned within the scrollview / how it reacts when you scroll the scrollView

Comment: I found the solution: Turn off Auto Layout

Comment: Ah you layed out the cellView via IB?

Comment: Yes, because I needed to do something with it